# Passing a variable from batch to powershell, and back to batch does not bring back the modified variable

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

So, my intention is to grab a directory from a text file (ex., "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ubisoft\Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Vegas 2") pass it to a powershell script (if necessary) to replace the apostrophe properly for a powershell command in loop.bat to replace text in .xml files.

ReplaceD.bat, passing variable:

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "replace.ps1" "%var%"
```

replace.ps1, receiving variable & modifying it:

```
param($dir)
$dir.replace('Tom Clancy''s','Tom Clancy''''s')
cmd /c 'pause'
Start-Process loop.bat $dir
```

When passing the variable from ReplaceD.bat to replace.ps1, the variable is fine and well. However...

loop.bat, receiving variable, with some problems:

```
@echo off
set dir=%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8
set r=C:\Program Files (x86)\Ubisoft\Tom Clancy''s Rainbow Six Vegas 2\Binaries\

echo Your variable is: %dir%
pause

:loop
echo Converting .xml file directory paths...
for %%a in ("Task Scheduler tasks\*.xml") do powershell -Command "(gc '%%a') -replace [regex]::Escape('%r%'), ('%dir%\Binaries\') | Out-File -encoding UTF8 'Task Scheduler tasks\%%~naNEW.xml'"

:end
```

When it passes it to loop.bat, it outputs the variable like this: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ubisoft\Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Vegas 2", when it's supposed to be: "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Ubisoft\Tom Clancy''s Rainbow Six Vegas 2**"

Without the extra apostrophe in "Tom Clancy's", I can't use the powershell command in loop.bat. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do everything in PowerShell and don't have to bother about this?

Comment: Well, I'm not so adept to Powershell, and I just want to experiment with this. I have more batch knowledge, by a little bit. I'm fully aware there is probably an easier solution by Powershell alone, but if possible, I just want to know what the problem might be.

Comment: Well, 70% of your code is already PowerShell, besides, it's always a good day to learning PowerShell :)

Comment: Haha, good point. xD I've left out some code from the first batch to cut to the point. I've already learned so much from just the syntax portion alone. In any case, I'm taking this as a learning experience, I'd appreciate the solution in Powershell and/or batch. I've just been itching my head at this for a while now... to learn the logic.

Comment: It's basically half the reason I'm learning it this way, so I can get a better grasp at the language with something I'm more familiar with. It's not the most practical, but it gives me a challenge.

Comment: One thing I see - in your replace.ps1 you are not changing the contents of your $dir variable when you do `$dir.replace('Tom Clancy''s','Tom Clancy''''s')`.  That is only outputting the result to the console.  You probably want to change that to `$dir = $dir.replace('Tom Clancy''s','Tom Clancy''''s')`

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but seems like `SET Var=%Var:'=''%` would do what you want without ever using PowerShell.

Comment: Late response, but thank you, both of you! The powershell version worked, and the batch file version worked as well.